# Regex inside Sublime .tmLanguage

Tags: c++, regex, sublimetext3, tmlanguage

I need to write some regex to improve C++.tmLanguage file. For example I want to highlight assertions from Google Test framework. Example:

```
ASSERT_EQ(expected, actual);
```

so I wrote this:

```
ASSERT_[A-Z_]+
```

but when I'm adding open parenthesis highlight is broken. Also I would like to highlight function name after range operator, example:

```
Foo::function()
```

but same issue here.

Please help.

Edit:

Maybe other regex from .tmLanguage interfere in some way? I've tried several solutions, all of them worked in web regex testers, but still no effect in Sublime.

Comment: did you try this `ASSERT_[A-Z_\W]+`?

Comment: How do you add the paren? Maybe you need to escape it `\(`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Please [edit] your question to very carefully describe **exactly** what you're trying to do, **exactly** which regexes you're trying, and **exactly** what your results are. As a regex aid, use http://rubular.com/ and select Ruby 1.9.2 at the bottom - that's the same regex flavor as being used by Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

ASSERT_EQ is highlighted in Sublime Text 3's C++ mode.